# Load file using SparkContext.addFile and load the file using load or csv method

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to load a [Testfile](http://(https://mywebsite/TestFile.csv)) using spark and java. Code is working fine in client mode(in my local machine) but It's giving **FileNotFound** Exception in cluster mode(i.e. on the server).

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                     .builder()
                     .config("spark.mesos.coarse","true")
                     .config("spark.scheduler.mode","FAIR")
                     .appName("1")
                     .master("local")
                     .getOrCreate();

  spark.sparkContext().addFile("https://mywebsiteurl/TestFile.csv");
  String[] fileServerUrlArray = fileServerUrl.split("/");
  fileName = fileServerUrlArray[fileServerUrlArray.length - 1];
  String file = SparkFiles.get(fileName);
  String modifiedFile="file://"+file;

  spark.read()
       .option("header", "true")
       .load(modifiedFile);   //getting FileNotFoundException in this line
```

> getting FileNotFound Exception.

Comment: I don't think Spark needs the 'file://' prefix. It uses a FileSystem object (depending on the FS it runs on: HDFS/S3/local etc.) with which it lists and loads files and/or base paths

Comment: Try to add recursive true to addFile method.
spark.sparkContext().addFile("https://mywebsiteurl/TestFile.csv", recursive: true);

print the file path for the file string:
String file = SparkFiles.get(fileName); If it gives correct worker node path, it means, addFile is working.

Make sure you comment these below line:
spark.read().option("header", "true").load(modifiedFile); to prevent FileNotFound Exception.

Answer (score 0):

While running your job in cluster mode, spark will never write on local area of the driver. Best option will be to `collect()` or use `toLocalIterator()` if you can read the file in buffer. Please try using below code and share if it's working for you?

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._

val conf = new Configuration()
val fs = path.getFileSystem(conf)    
val hdfspath = new Path("hdfs:///user/home/testFile.dat")
val localpath = new Path("file:///user/home/test/")

fs.copyToLocalFile(hdfspath,localpath)
```